# My game Show some extra space in below on Mobile Device

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am developed one Game using HTML ,CSS & JavaScript and it is responsive on Desktop but if I will try to make it responsive on Mobile then it show some extra Blue Color Space at bottom . Can anyone help to tackle this problem?

Website is live [here](https://yashjee003.github.io/guessnumber.github.io/)

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMsnr.jpg)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #001e6c;
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
}

main {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  width: 40%;
  padding: 2rem 2rem;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 5px;
}
.welcome-screen {
  height: auto;
}
img {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin: 3rem auto;
}

h2 {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  margin-top: 2.5rem;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
.event-buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2rem 1rem;
}
button {
  margin: 0.5rem auto;
  padding: 1.8rem;
  color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#001e6c, #035397);
  border-radius: 1rem;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.15rem;
  font-family: Sans;
  width: 59%;
}
button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 1px #032322;
}
#button-child {
  background: linear-gradient(#673fd7, #673fd7);
}

/* // User Play area  */

.user-guess {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.user-guess input {
  padding: 2rem 4rem;
  border-style: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#guess-result {
  margin: 30px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 1.2rem auto;
}

#guess-result .attempts {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: red;
}

.info {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

#event-screen {
  height: auto;
  /* margin-top: 50px; */
}

/* // Responsive */

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  body {
    /* width: 10; */
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 21px;
    margin-top: 1rem;
  }

  main {
    width: 100%;
    border-width: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    height: fit-content;
    height: max-content;
    height: auto;
  }
  img {
    max-width: 67%;
  }
  button {
    width: 82%;
    margin: 0.5rem auto;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  .user-guess input {
    padding: 1.2rem 1rem;
    text-align: center;
  }

  h3 {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
  }
  .info {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  #guess-result .attempts {
    margin-top: 9px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans:wght@300;400&family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,500;1,500&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body onload="randomNumber()">
    <main>
      <!-- Welcome Screen -->
      <section id="welcome-screen">
        <div id="title-image">
          <h2>Guess The Random Number Between 1-100</h2>
          <img src="/images/game.svg" alt="logo" />
        </div>

        <div id="event_guess">
          <h2>Select The Difficulty</h2>
          <div class="event-buttons">
            <button onclick="easyMode()">Easy: 10 Attempts</button>
            <button onclick="hardMode()" id="button-child">
              Hard: 5 Attempts
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <!-- Event Screen -->

      <section id="event-screen">
        <div id="even-button">
          <button onclick="startNewGame()" id="event-button">New Game</button>
        </div>
        <div class="user-guess">
          <h2>Your Guess</h2>
          <input
            type="number"
            name="Guess"
            id="guess-number"
            placeholder="Enter your Guess"
            onchange="userData()"
            ;
          />
        </div>

        <div id="guess-result">
          <div class="info">
            <h3>Number of previous attempts</h3>
            <span class="attempts">0</span>
          </div>

          <div class="info">
            <h3>Number of previous guesses</h3>
            <span class="attempts" id="previous">0</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
    <script src="/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: apply `height: 100vh;` to `main`

Comment: Take a look at my answer, as well as my edit suggestion

Answer (score 0):

As @SigurdMazanti says:

> apply `height: 100vh;` to `main`

This would look like:

```css
main {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100vh; /* New line */
  padding: 2rem 2rem;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 5px;
}
```

For the `width`, you are using a percentage, which is only relative to the parent container. For the `height` though, we are going to use `vh`, `viewport height`, which is relative to the window size rather than the parent container.

That should do it~

Comment: Yes it will work . I have add   height: 100vh; in main under media query. Thanks for the Help